# Google AdWords v201206 DotNet Client GetClientReport trouble

Tags: c#, .net, google-ads-api

Here's what I'm doing:

```
Selector selector = new Selector();
selector.fields = new string[] {"CampaignId", "AdGroupId", "Id", "CriteriaType", "Criteria", "CriteriaDestinationUrl", "Clicks", "Impressions", "Cost"};
Predicate predicate = new Predicate();
predicate.field = "Status";
predicate.@operator = PredicateOperator.IN;
predicate.values = new string[] { "ACTIVE", "PAUSED" };
selector.predicates = new Predicate[] { predicate };

ReportDefinition definition = new ReportDefinition();
definition.reportName = "criteria report";
definition.reportType = ReportDefinitionReportType.CRITERIA_PERFORMANCE_REPORT;
definition.downloadFormat = DownloadFormat.XML;
definition.dateRangeType = ReportDefinitionDateRangeType.YESTERDAY;
definition.selector = selector;
definition.includeZeroImpressions = true;

_handler.RunReport(new AdWordsUser(), definition);
```

And here's my handler method:

```
public void RunReport(AdWordsUser user, ReportDefinition definition)
{

    if (definition != null)
    {

        string reportContents = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            ReportUtilities utilities = new ReportUtilities(user);
            utilities.ReportVersion = "v201206";
            ClientReport report = utilities.GetClientReport(definition);
            reportContents = report.Contents.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _errorHandler.AddError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Where I step through I get this error:

```
Report contents are invalid. - !!!2|||-1|||[ReportDefinitionError.CUSTOMER_SERVING_TYPE_REPORT_MISMATCH @ selector]???
```

Been searching for hours trying to find a solution. Any hints?

Comment: Looks like it may be related to not specifying the customerClientID on the request.  Still trying to figure out how to add that to the request with the dotnet client.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the issue is indeed needing to pass in the customerClientID.

[This document](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/reporting) helped me picture what was going on.

I ended up modifying my code like this:

```
var configOptions = new Dictionary<string,string>();
configOptions.Add("clientCustomerID", customerID.ToString());
_handler.RunReport(new AdWordsUser(configOptions), definition);
```